# Office.context.roamingSettings.get returns undefined

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm working with a web add-in on outlook online, We have a customer property need to store in the roamingSettings and we will get it from the roamingsetting next time user open our add-in. but some how, for some specified user, the get method returns undefined it's really wired. 
Here is my code to save

```
var hideGuide = false;
    Office.context.roamingSettings.set("hideOCGuide", currentShowGuidBox.getValue());
                    Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync();
```

Here is the code to get it from roamingSettings

```
hideGuide = Office.context.roamingSettings.get("hideOCGuide");
```

I have the debug with the code, the property value can be saved after I run the saveAsync method, but the get method returns undefined.
Notice that there is an error when office js init.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YesrH.png)

Is this an bug for office.js?
Any help will be appreciate

Comment: If your question is *"Is this an bug for office.js?"* the answer is no. Instead you would need to debug the code, nobody can do this for you. Some hints what you should look at: 1. `currentShowGuidBox.getValue()` check it returns something, log it; 2. `Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync()` is asynchronous function and you need to wait for completion. After completion you can check callback `Office.AsyncResult` for any errors; 3. `Office.context.roamingSettings.get` must be called inside the body of `Office.initialize`; This is just a few to start. Please do your work.

Comment: Jason, can you please share the details of the browser you are using? And have does the error reproduce on other browsers as well?

Comment: Hi MSFT,  this error only happens on a specified user in our tenant, I have tried it on Microsoft Edge, Chrome and Firefox, but I can't get the details for the browsers, sorry for that, the issue exists on each browser, it's really weird.

Comment: Can you please provide the email ID of the user ?

Comment: Please tell if this is in compose mode? Also can you please share the screenshots for the same.

Comment: Sorry for replying late, this issue only occurred in one of our customer, but Now I didn't get any response from the customer, will update the issue if I get any update.

Answer (score -1):

Just check your roaming settings content using a tool like OutlookSpy.
See [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/netframework/en-US/22a0ab3e-ea64-4741-aadf-9e51adbb54d2/how-to-get-roamingsettings-stored-with-officejs-api-from-vstocom-addin?forum=outlookdev) for details.

Comment: This doesn't provide any answer.

Comment: Well I thought I said the same thing as you: debug the code.

Comment: Sorry Victor, I didn't meant to offence you in any way and appreciate your time to put into community resource. The difference is: I wrote the comment and you wrote the answer. Answer on SO is something useful for everybody who is looking for info on similar question/topic. More on [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)